# How to set featureCompatibilityVersion on secondary replica set member which does not startup due to this error?

Tags: mongodb

I'm situation were I am trying to get a broken member of a replica set back online. I have followed the normal procedure of deleting the data in /data/db and trying to sync. Also tried to move all the data from one secondary to the other and restart mongo. Each time I get the standard error above complaining about compatibility issues. Now the servers are the same version 3.6. So why was this an issue?... Must be that the featureCompatibilityVersion=3.6 while on the other server are set to featureCompatibilityVersion=3.4 which they are. However to see this the server needs to startup but since it kept restarting I could not check that. So I removed it from the replica set started it up and seen it was set to featureCompatibilityVersion=3.6. So I changed this to 3.4 and started it up again while part of replica set but still had the same issue. How do I get round this?

The other servers have featureCompatibilityVersion=3.4 so if I was syncing correctly would the other server not pull in admin collection which would have featureCompatibilityVersion=3.4. So why does this keep complaining?
If not how do you change this on a server which does not startup? Is there something in mongo config I can set?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here's probably not a helpful answer, just a sanity check: remove replSet parameter and spin up the mongod totally solo.... does that work ok?

I only suggest it cause I can't see what your issue is and maybe this would find something...wouldn't take long, may not help...   the versioning I don't quite get...

Comment: Yeah that works fine. I did this removing replica info from mongo config. However it says compatibility feature = 3.6. So I change this try to add to replica set again and get same issue. However the other replicas have this set to 3.4. Have no idea why it would be doing this.

Comment: go to mongo's site - they just started a community forum there - cause it is brand new I think employees are monitoring it and you should get particularly good participation....

Comment: Thanks. Will take that up